# NPE when I set my customized ListView Layout

Tags: android, listview

I created a customized layout for a `listview`, but when I run the App it crashes and and `logcat` says: `NPE`. any idea why that happens?

Cutomized_layout"inside layout folder"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Code:

```
ListView mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.listviewlayout, android.R.id.text1, str);
```

Logcat:

```
05-28 13:01:18.197: E/AndroidRuntime(31484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 13:01:18.197: E/AndroidRuntime(31484): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 13:01:18.197: E/AndroidRuntime(31484):    at   
android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
05-28 13:01:18.197: E/AndroidRuntime(31484):    at  
android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
05-28 13:01:18.197: E/AndroidRuntime(31484):    at 
android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2627)
05-28 13:01:18.197: E/AndroidRuntime(31484):    at 
android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1259)
```

Comment: what is the name of your "customized layout inside layout folder"

Comment: @user2450263 it is "listviewlayout"

Comment: can u post the entire error stack trace from Logat? And can you try using your activity context instead of application context?

Comment: change this `android.R.id.text1` to `R.id.tv` and try

Comment: @Elpharaoh Please ensure that, in the third parameter in your array adapter you provide the exact id of the textview in your "listviewlayout". please try it and inform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this:

```
ListView mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
        R.layout.listviewlayout, R.id.tv, str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
        R.layout.listviewlayout, android.R.id.text1, str);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
        R.layout.listviewlayout, R.id.tv, str);
```

You need to pass your `listviewlayout TextView` id `android:id="@+id/tv"` as 3rd Parameter of `ArrayAdapter`